# SQL Server ignores proper index with included column

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have `tblClaims(ClaimID, ValidityTo, ...)` and `tblClaimServices(ClaimServiceId, ClaimID, ValidityTo, ....)` with an obvious foreign key on ClaimID. The ValidityTo is used for history, so actual data has ValidityTo=null.

These tables have respectively 3 million and 13 million rows.

The query:

```
select * from tblClaimServices where ClaimID=1234567 and ValidityTo is null
```

takes 5 seconds to execute !
Querying `... where ClaimID=1234567` is instantaneous.
Note that we're not doing select * but specifying almost all columns. This is an ORM (Django)

The explain plan shows that it's using a **clustered** index on (ClaimServiceID, ValidityTo) and then working hard to query the ClaimID within those. That's insane ! ValidityTo is null for 98% of the rows.

We created an index on (ClaimID, ValidityTo) but it wasn't used. We then created an index on ClaimID with an included column for validityto:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_test1 ON tblClaimServices (ClaimID) include (ValidityTo) WHERE ValidityTo IS NULL
```

But wasn't used either. (So taking 5 seconds to find 0 to 10 rows)

However, using a hint

```
from tblClaimServices with (index(idx_test1))
```

Does work great. Instant results.

Now, I can't and don't want to have to include hints. SQL Server should be able to use an index that is so specific ! And it would require me to update an old app that uses a ORM and including the hints there would be a major pain. And make the app pretty fragile or become very slow in other queries.

How can I improve SQL Server's decision to use that proper index ?

Comment: `SELECT *` means all columns, so all those columns are going to have to be in the `INCLUDE`

Comment: I get you but the goal of such an index should be to find the rows that have this ClaimID and then get the specific rows from the actual table. There are very few. If we include all columns in the index, it's just another copy of the table... ‍♂️ And since the hint allows an instant access, why is SQL Server not using it ?

Comment: Very dependent on whether the compiler thinks it is worth using it, which depends on statistics. Are there statistics on this index? There should be filtered statistics with the same name `select * from sys.stats where name ='idx_test1'` Note that since your index is filtered it wouldn't actually be a full copy of the table. You shouldn't really do `select *` anyway

Comment: It comes down to whether SQL Server costs the need to do lookups to get the missing columns as more expensive than just scanning the whole of an index that **does** have the missing columns. This is just a matter of it comparing the two options with its cost model. When you use the hint what are the estimated number of executions vs actual number of executions for the lookup operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this strange behavior disappeared when the database was in 2012 compatibility mode. In a more recent mode, the database avoids using the date index validity_to.

We do have a similar field that points from soft-deleted records to the current one which is an integer. Replacing the date condition ( `is null` ) with the integer makes all these queries use the index properly and return results immediately.

I am still not 100% sure why the index isn't used for the validity_to but my problem is solved.